# Web3-eth-debug "Debug is not a constructor"

Tags: solidity, web3js

I use nodejs to execute a javascript that interacts with my local instance of Ganache. I would like to use the [web3-eth-debug](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-debug.html) module to get information about my transactions. However after installing the module with `npm i web3-eth-debug` or `npm i -g web3-eth-debug` and running the following Javascript code I get the error `TypeError: Debug is not a constructor`.

My code:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')
const fs = require('fs');
const Debug = require('web3-eth-debug')
const options = {
    transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1,
}
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"), null, options);
const debug = new Debug(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"), null, options);
...
```

Is the debug module supposed to be imported or constructed differently? What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you should import it exactly as shown in that link that you provided - `import {Debug} from 'web3-eth-debug';`.

Comment: Which implies to me that you can achieve the same with `const Debug = require('web3-eth-debug').Debug`.

Comment: I believe that the debug module exports an object (i.e., something like `module.exports = {...}`), in contrast with the web3 module, which exports a class.

Comment: And I'm saying all of this just by reading the example from the docs that you've linked here.

Comment: Thanks that solved it for me! If you would like to post it as an answer I'll confirm it. nodejs doesn't allow the ```import {Debug} from 'web3-eth-debug';``` notation and I didn't realise this was how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coding example in the link that you provided shows:

```
import {Debug} from 'web3-eth-debug';
```

Which implies that you should do something like:

```
const Debug = require('web3-eth-debug').Debug
```

When comparing the two `import` statements in the coding example:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import {Debug} from 'web3-eth-debug';
```

I conclude that while the Web3 module exports a class (i.e., something like `module.exports = class ...`), the Debug module exports an object (i.e., something like `module.exports = {...}`).